# What is causing the 'Image Decode' performance differences between my phone and my PC?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, game-development, developer-tools, drawimage

I am currently developing a 2D game using Javascript and Canvas.

The game runs perfectly on my 8 year-old PC, on my Samsung S21 FE however, I get a lot of freezes.

The built-in performance tab of Chrome gives me the following results:

PC:

[image]

Mobile:

[image]

In the performance tab on my PC I see the relative time spent on paining is extremely low, on my phone however, this is enormous.

Digging down deeper, I notice that 'Image Decode' takes around 0.1% of the total time on PC, on my phone this is 94%.

What is causing this 'Image Decode' problem on my phone?

Comment: You should only decode images once when loading.  To me it looks like you are loading the images every frame. Without code we can only guess

Comment: Looks like the browser discards the bitmap info after use to save some memory space, and instead re-decodes the image from scratch every time. You might want to store ImageBitmap objects instead (and preferably at the correct scale if your original image is big) so that the browser keeps only the bitmap in memory. But I concur with the previous comment, we need to see your code to tell you exactly how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

The performance issues were related to drawing huge images with canvas. Ditching the 4k assets resolved my problems.